# Check if Point belongs to LineString in Geotools

Tags: geotools

Is there any way to check with Geotools if a point is placed on a LineString?

I am trying to retrieve street names of a route obtained from a routing algorithm. The route is displayed in gps coordinates and i was thinking to look for the name of the street by checking if the point is placed on the LineString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a built in function that does that but you could make your own by testing if a small circle/square around your point intersects a street feature.

It is likely that if you even super close to a road, numerical error would creep in and no amount of testing would say a point is EXACTLY ON a segment. (unless it was a vertex point)